# Automated Script to "Add to xxxx"

Tags: perl, wget

I want to login to a website and automatically do some action like say Add to some place.. which is like clicking a submit button, followed by another such click. Is there some way that I can automate this.

Also, how can we protect our websites against such things.

P.S : This is only for information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm)

Answer (score 1):

[iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for ui automation.